# Upload file using RestFull API in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, restful-url

I want to upload a file to specific directory using restfull API developped in symfony.

my form type is given as follow:

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder
        ->add('file', 'file')

        ->add('listuser','textarea', array('error_bubbling' => true, 'required' => false));

}
```

in Restlet Client, I want to pass the URL of the file, and then in my controller I want to upload the file to specific directory
[image]

for example, the URL of the file passed in restlet client is:

```
 "file": "C:\wamp\www\uploads\test.jpeg"
```

so I want to get this file and upload it to my directory.

I tried several code but no one work.

Any Help please

Comment: You add into form `file` control, but send `string` via client. You must use file stream or download file from passed url (to example, using curl).

Comment: you use guzzle (or other tools) to call your api rest from your application front that contains form file or you use the same application for rest api and front?

Comment: I use the same application for rest api and front, always I get this message "Invalid json message received", and same time other errors about the url.